# .tpl file not load document in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I try to load j Query in .tpl file As below code

File name  `html_header.tpl`

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("No where...");
        });
</script>
</head>
```

its not working Please help me .

Comment: see the console, are you getting any errors? Have you included jquery?

Comment: Yes i am getting error in console  TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function element.attachEvent("on"+actualEventName,responder);}

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the library. Try this way:

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("No where...");
        });
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: I am getting another jquery error from other js file Include jquery version 3.1.1.min.js

Comment: @Ket, good point, I have edited my answer to load it form the correct location

Comment: Thanks @Lajos Arpad.

Comment: @Ket, you are welcome. If my answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.